# find character within a string sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a string column called *day* with indexes of the days of week as follows

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I want to check if *for example* 1 exists in the string within the column.

the logic should be like this.

```
select * from table where 1 is in day;
```

how can I achieve this with psql?

Comment: `position('1' in columnname) > 0`. But in general it's a bad idea to store comma separated items in a column, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: thanks @jarlh. it's only for the week days and not a long string. I don't wanna create a relation table only for this logic.

Comment: @Garine you can always set this column as array type

Comment: You should fix your data model.  You should not be storing multiple values -- particularly numbers -- in a string.  Under some circumstances as an array, but more often as a junction/association table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table
where position('1' in day) > 0
```

But in general it's a bad idea to store comma separated items in a column, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place.

The solution using `like` or `position()` can fail if you have two-digit numbers in those values, e.g. `'12,13'` would be found by `position('1' in day)` as well.

To avoid that, convert the de-normalized value into an array, then search in the array:

```
select * 
from the_table
where '1' = any(string_to_array(day, ','));
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GEMN57014

Answer (score 1):

Another way You can try to use `like`

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T(col1 varchar(50));

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('1,2,3,4,5,6,7');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2,3,4,5,6,7,1');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('5,6,7');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from T
WHERE col1 like concat('%','1',',%') or  col1 like concat('%,','1','%')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a6990/2/0)**:

```
|          col1 |
|---------------|
| 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |
| 2,3,4,5,6,7,1 |
```